# Mathematica displays the unevaluated expression Expectation function

Tags: evaluation

The evaluation runs for a few seconds and then Mathematica displays the unevaluated expression `Expectation` function

```
Expectation[(((w + a)*Exp[r*T]) + (s*Exp[d*T] + o*l)*P*
   Exp[(r - d - (1/2)*q^2)*T + (x*Sqrt[T]*q)])^(1-c), x \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[0, 1]]
```

the value of parameters are:

```
{{d -> 0.0269, q -> 0.3315, r -> 0.0435, T -> 1, w -> 1.1465, 
  p -> 100, l -> 1, c -> 3,a -> 0.0941, s -> 0.0029, o -> 0.0089}}
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: (i) I think you are looking for trouble by using notation like o*l which can easily be mis-read.  (ii) Add Assumptions -> {r >0, etc}  will help solve symbolic problems. (iii) Use `NExpectation` for numerical problems (given numerical parameter values):  otherwise keep things symbolic.

Answer (score 4):

```
expr = (((w + a) Exp[r t]) + (s Exp[d t] + o*l) p Exp[(r - d - (1/2)*q^2) t + 
       (x Sqrt[t]*q)])^(1 - c) /. 
       {d -> 0.0269, q -> 0.3315, r -> 0.0435, t -> 1, w -> 1.1465, p -> 100,
        l -> 1, c -> 3, a -> 0.0941, s -> 0.0029,  o -> 0.0089};

NExpectation[expr, x \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[0, 1]]
(* 0.171448 *)
```

From [Expectation >> Properties and Relations](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Expectation.html):

> [image]

Therefore, you can also use the following, slower, alternatives:

```
N@Expectation[expr, x \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[0, 1]]
(*  0.171448 *)
```

Or, when symbolic evaluation

```
Expectation[expr, x \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[0, 1]]
```

returns

[image]

use

```
N[%]
```

to get the same value `0.171448` for expectation.